# Double of Float always returning 0.0 in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, double, percentage, calculation

I am trying to convert a number into a percentage, something I though would be pretty simple, but for some reason it always returns 0.0 and I can't figure out why. I have tried Double and Float and both return 0.0. It makes no sense. The code is rather simple...

```
struct ProgressView: View {
  @ObservableObject var state: MyState = MyState.shared

  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      if state.times.currentDay > 0 {
        let num: Int64 = Int64((609 * 100) / Int64(1800))
        let percent = Double(num / 100)
        RingSpinner(newValue: (percent > 1.0) ? 0.99 : percent)
          .onAppear {
            print("The value of currentDay: \(state.times.currentDay)")
            print("The num is: \(num)")
            print("The percent is: \(percent)")
          }
      }
      //rest of my view code...
    }
  }
}
```

In my console I can see the following

> The value of the currentDay is: 609
>
> The num is: 33
>
> The percent is: 0.0

the percent should be `0.33` or at least something close to that, but it is always 0.0

Just for clarification, the `state.times.goal` is 30 * 60 (30 minutes in seconds)

I have tried switching he Double to a Float and I still get 0.0 in the console. I don't understand how it is 0.0, it makes no sense to me. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Side Note: If you are wondering why I am using Int64 it's because the `currentDay` variable can be a very.... very large number. Like 4 hours 34 minutes converted to seconds, then multiplied by 100. I originally was using Int16 but was getting arithmetic overflow errors so I had to change it to Int64 to handle the large initial number.

Comment: This needs a [mre], but in general I'd say that `@State` is *not* a good solution for this. `@State` is for value types that are modified *in* the `View` or via `Binding`. The fact that you have a singleton makes me think you may want an `ObservableObject` with a `@Published` property

Comment: You are correct sir, I actually am using an `@ObservedObject` in my code, I just mistyped it when I was posting it up. Also, I updated to code to remove the variables and show a minimum reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured it out. The problem was because the `num` variable was Int64 when dividing that by 100 it was always 0. I had to cast the `num` variable to a Double, then do the division. Since the main number had already been divided by the daily goal the number would be small enough to fit into a Double. So what I needed was...

```
var body: some View {
  ZStack {
    if state.times.currentDay > 0 {
      let num: Int64 = Int64((state.times.currentDay * 100 / Int64(State.times.goal))
      let percent = Double(Double(num) / 100.0)
      ...
  }
}
```

That cast to a Double when doing the division worked.

Comment: The `/` was used on two `Int` values so it represents an integer division. If you cast the num to a Double the division is precise. So `let percent = Double(num) / 100` should also work to make your code a little bit cleaner.